# How are PHP sessions saved by default?

Tags: php, session

I have not changed any of the configuration options for sessions in my php.ini.

```
session.save_handler = "files"
session.save_path    = ""
session_save_path()  = ""
```

From what I read, if I change php.ini to something like, session.save_path = "c:\tmp\", all the session will be stored as files in c:\tmp.

My question is, how/where are the sessions being stored when I use the default configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would imagine it's wherever your OS stores temp files by default

In *nix it's /tmp/

In Windows I believe it's C:\Windows\Temp

Answer (score 1):

They should be saved in the system temporary directory - usually something like c:\windows\temp